# read wsgi post data with unicode encoding

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-3.4

How can i read wsgi POST with unicode encoding,

this is part of my code :

```
....
request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
req = str(environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size))
```

and from `req` i read my fileds,

this is what i posted :

```
کلمه
```

and this is what i read it from inside of py code:

```
b"%DA%A9%D9%84%D9%85%D9%87"
```

This is a byte string but i can't convert it or read it ,
I use encode and decode methods but none of these are not worked .

I use python3.4 and wsgi and mod_wsgi(apache2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `urllib` module of python, with this code and worked :

```
fm = urllib.parse.parse_qs(request_body['family'].encode().decode(),True) # return a dictionary 
familyvalue = str([k for k in fm.keys()][0]) # access to first item
```

is this a right way ?